# I want to install Ubuntu without losng data on other partitions

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation, data-loss

I have two partitions D and E. In D window is installed and in E I have imporatant data. I want to remove windows and install ubuntu but without losing any data on E.
How should I do it.

Comment: I'd suggest using "*Something else*" which is the Manual Partitioning system letting you choose exactly what you want. I prefer it, but backup first as always.

Comment: @karel: What a terrible **"duplicated"** question. Out of six answers only one even mentions an EFI partition, and that answer does not answer the OP's question of how not to overwrite a valuable data partition. The answer does mention installing next to Windows, but the OP does not want that, he wants to **remove Windows**.